# StructureMap registry isn't working for generic interfaces

Tags: structuremap

```
public class RepositoryRegistry : Registry
    {
        public RepositoryRegistry()
        {
            Scan(x =>
            {
                x.Assembly("MyApp.Data");
                x.TheCallingAssembly();
                x.WithDefaultConventions();                
                x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(ILookupRepo<>));                      
            });

            var tmp = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILookupRepo<User>>();

            Debug.WriteLine(ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave());
        }
    }
```

Getting this error:

```
{"StructureMap Exception Code:  202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily MyApp.Data.Repositories.Lookup.ILookupRepo`1[[MyApp.Data.Context.User, MyApp.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], TolMobile.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
```

StructureMap can't seem to resolve `IAnything<T>`.  Is there any reason why this would stop working? I've used this in another project in the exact same way and it resolves ok. The only difference is that the version of StructureMap I am now using is newer...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a StructureMap issue - no type inherits from `ILookupRepo<>`.

This is an open generic type, not a base type! If you want to find types closing on `ILookupRepo<>`, then you need to scan like this:

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.Assembly("MyApp.Data");
    x.TheCallingAssembly();
    x.WithDefaultConventions();                
    x.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(ILookupRepo<>));
});
```

[There's a blog post on the topic.](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/12/18/advanced-structuremap-connecting-implementations-to-open-generic-types/)

Comment: What if my actual LookupRepo class implements ILookupRepo, should it not resolve then?

Comment: If `ILookupRepo` was not generic at all, or if you were registering `x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(ILookupRepo<User>))`, then this would work. Think of open generic types as being like a template, not a base class.

Comment: Is ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing a new feature introduced in StructureMap?  I definitely had this working on a project about a year+ ago using the AddAllTypesOf(typeof(ILookupRepo<>))

Comment: @jaffa, I don't think it's a new feature - and the blog post confirms this, it's 3 years old, so the feature must be at least as old. I guess something must have been different in your other project.